# Should modification of the asdict result modify the original object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine I have

```
class DictWrapper:
    def __init__(self, dictionary=None):
        if dictionary is None:
            dictionary = {}
        self.dictionary = dictionary
```

With a bunch of methods that operate on the wrapped dictionary, keep it adherent to some format, pull information from it etc.

Should I return the actual internal object from `asdict`

```
def asdict(self):
    return self.dictionary
```

or a deepcopy of it? What's the standard/expectation?

Comment: The default is a shallow copy.

Comment: That `dictionary={}` default probably isn't doing what you think it is, by the way.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica oh yeah that's why I had `dictionary=None`, I totally forgot why I wrote it when I just opened this code again. I remember now and I'll have to add a comment. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @minseong why does it have to be `dictionary=None`?

Comment: @Programmer python will reuse the same default parameter every time, so any modification to it will mean the next time the method is invoked with default parameter, it already has values

Comment: @minseong ok, I thought this only applies for function and not for method parameters !